# Salesforce - Error "DML requires SObject or SObject list type: account"

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

whenever I try to create an account object using apex they give me errors like "DML requires SObject or SObject list type: account". but other objects correctly working.

Comment: post your code? Any chance you created your own class or variable and named it `Account`, thus "hiding" (shadowing) the name of the sobject?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but answering this so that someone may benefit from it.

Without any code to review, it may be difficult to point out but one reason could be that you are using set and not a list in your DML statement.
For instance

```
Set<SBQQ__Quote__c> quotes = new  Set<SBQQ__Quote__c>();
.. some code 

if(!quotelines.isEmpty()){
        upsert quotelines;
  }
```

will throw the same error

> DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Set<SBQQ__Quote__c>

To handle this issue, you could convert Set to List as below

```
if(!quotes.isEmpty()){
       update new List<SBQQ__Quote__c>(quotes);
}
```

DML only accepts SObject like `SBQQ__Quote__c` or `List<SBQQ__Quote__c>`